# SQL: Inserting rows into a table for multiple values at one

Tags: sql, join, select, sql-insert

See file attached for more clarity and example.

I have a table that tracks the profit made, per fruit/variety/country for a company that sells fruits.

[Profit Table] has 4 columns ( Fruit, Country, F Variety, Profit). For a specific, Country and Variety, some records will have "none" as a Variety.

For each of the records that has a "none", I want to be able to insert a duplicate record for the profit value for each of the [Variety List] varieties and apply the "none" record to it , but ignore any variety that already has a profit associated with it for a specific Fruit and Country.

I am able to do an insert into but for one country at a time...Would appreciate to know how do we use a lookup on VarietyList table ( knowing that this can't be harcoded as there may be new varieties )

The image has an example of the input tables and desired outputs:

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you use: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Show parts you can do & explain about how you are stuck going further towards your goal.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can select records in table `profitTable` that have `fruitVariety` set to `'None'`, then `cross join` with `varietyList`, and use `not exists` to evict combinations that already exist in the table.

```
insert into profitTable (fruit, country, fruitVariety, profit)
select pt.fruit, pt.country, vl.variety, pt.profit
from profitTable pt
cross join varietyList vl 
where
    pt.fruitVariety = 'None'
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from profitTable pt1
        where 
            pt1.fruit = pt.fruit
            and pt1.country = pt.country 
            and pt1.fruitVariety = vl.variety
    )
```